# Calculate mean, variance and range using Bash script

Tags: bash, numeric

Given a file file.txt:

```
AAA 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 2 3 
BBB 3 2 3 34 56 1 
CCC 4 7 4 6 222 45
```

Does any one have any ideas on how to calculate the mean, variance and range for each item, i.e. AAA, BBB, CCC respectively using Bash script? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in Bash?

Comment: Note that bash proper does not do floating point arithmetic. You'll have to use something like `bc`

Comment: To elaborate on the above comments: does all the logic actually need to be in Bash, or can you invoke an external utility such as `awk` or `bc` or (best yet) `perl`? In the latter case -- do you have any preference as to the utility?

Comment: @ruakh Sorry for the  mix-up..I'm new to Linux and kind of confused about the relationship between Bash and the utilities. Are't `awk` and `bc` commands of Bash?

Comment: @glenn jackman Could you elaborate a little bit hwo to use `bc` to solve this problem?

Comment: Bash is a shell, a program that allows you to issue commands either interactively or in scripts. Some of those commands are "built-in", meaning that they're actually part of Bash; other commands are external programs such as `awk` and so on. AWK is completely separate from Bash; a system can have Bash installed without having AWK installed, and vice versa.

Comment: @Adam Liss Could you elaborate a little bit how to use `awk` here to solve my problem?

Comment: @ruakh Thanks man. But if I use `awk` or `bc` in a script, is it still a bash script?

Comment: @BrianJames: For many purposes, yes; for others, no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution with `awk`, which calculates:

- minimum = smallest value on each line
- maximum = largest value on each line
- average = μ = sum of all values on each line, divided by the count of the numbers.
- variance = 1/n × [(Σx)² - Σ(x²)] where 
  n = number of values on the line = `NF` - 1 (in awk, `NF` = number of fields on the line)
  (Σx)² = square of the sum of the values on the line
  Σ(x²) = sum of the squares of the values on the line

```
awk '{
  min = max = sum = $2;       # Initialize to the first value (2nd field)
  sum2 = $2 * $2              # Running sum of squares
  for (n=3; n <= NF; n++) {   # Process each value on the line
    if ($n < min) min = $n    # Current minimum
    if ($n > max) max = $n    # Current maximum
    sum += $n;                # Running sum of values
    sum2 += $n * $n           # Running sum of squares
  }
  print $1 ": min=" min ", avg=" sum/(NF-1) ", max=" max ", var=" ((sum*sum) - sum2)/(NF-1);
}' filename
```

Output:

```
AAA: min=1, avg=3.45455, max=6, var=117.273
BBB: min=1, avg=16.5, max=56, var=914.333
CCC: min=4, avg=48, max=222, var=5253
```

Note that you can save the awk script (everything between, but not including, the single-quotes) in a file, say called `script`, and execute it with `awk -f script filename`

Comment: The definition of variance seems to be wrong, should it be `1/n × Σ(x-μ)²?`

Comment: @Brian - yes, that's the definition, but the implementations are equivalent.  It's a well-known optimization by statisticians; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_formula_for_the_variance for a proof.

Comment: Okay, I can do this on my own. Again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: my file size exceeds the maximun number of fields size for 'awk', is there a way to address this issue?

Comment: Try using `gawk` (GNU awk) if you aren't already, or if you're using `awk`, try the `-mf NNN`option to set the maximum number of fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `python`:

```
$ AAA() {  echo "$@" | python -c 'from sys import stdin; nums = [float(i) for i in stdin.read().split()]; print(sum(nums)/len(nums))'; }

$ AAA 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 2 3
3.45454545455
```

Comment: Thanks for speedy response. Is there any way that I can process the whole file?

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 (mean):

```
mean () {
  len=$#
  echo  $* | tr " " "\n" | sort -n | head -n $(((len+1)/2)) | tail -n 1
}

nMean () {
  echo -n "$1 " 
  shift 
  mean $* 
}
```

mean usage:

```
nMean AAA 3 4  5 6 3 4 3 6 2 4
4
```

Part 2 (variance):

```
variance () {
  count=$1
  avg=$2
  shift
  shift
  sum=0
  for n in $* 
  do 
    diff=$((avg-n))
    quad=$((diff*diff))
    sum=$((sum+quad))
  done 
  echo $((sum/count)) 
}

sum () {
  form="$(echo $*)"
  formula=${form// /+}
  echo $((formula))
}

nVariance () {
  echo -n "$1 " 
  shift 
  count=$#
  s=$(sum $*) 
  avg=$((s/$count))
  var=$(variance $count $avg $*)
  echo $var
}
```

usage:

```
nVariance AAA 3 4  5 6 3 4 3 6 2 4
1
```

Part 3 (range):

```
range () { 
  min=$1
  max=$1
  for p in $* ; do 
    (( $p < $min )) && min=$p
    (( $p > $max )) && max=$p
  done 
  echo $min ":" $max 
}

nRange () {
  echo -n "$1 " 
  shift 
  range $* 
}
```

usage:

```
nRange AAA 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 2 3 
AAA 1 : 6
```

nX is short for named X, named mean, named variance, ... .
Note, that I use integer arithmetic, which is, what is possible with the shell. To use floating point arithmetic, you would use bc, for instance. Here you loose precision, which might be acceptable for big natural numbers.

Process all 3 commands for an input line:

```
processLine () {
  nVariance $*
  nMean $*
  nRange $*
}
```

Read the data from a file, line by line:

```
# data:
# AAA 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 2 3 
# BBB 3 2 3 34 56 1 
# CCC 4 7 4 6 222 45 

while read line
do
  processLine $line
done < data
```

#### update:

Contrary to my expectation, it doesn't seem easy to handle an unknown number of arguments with functions in `bc`, for example `min (3, 4, 5, 2, 6)`.

But the need to call bc can be reduced to 2 places, if the input are integers. I used a precision of 2 ("scale=2") - you may change this to your needs.

```
variance () {
  count=$1
  avg=$2
  shift
  shift
  sum=0
  for n in $* 
  do 
    diff="($avg-$n)"
    quad="($diff*$diff)"
    sum="($sum+$quad)"
  done 
#  echo "$sum/$count" 
  echo "scale=2;$sum/$count" | bc 
}

nVariance () {
  echo -n "$1 " 
  shift 
  count=$#
  s=$(sum $*) 
  avg=$(echo "scale=2;$s/$count" | bc)
  var=$(variance $count $avg $*)
  echo $var
}
```

The rest of the code can stay the same. Please verify that the formula for the variance is correct - I used what I had in mind:

For values (1, 5, 9), I sum up (15) divide by count (3) => 5.
Then I create the diff to the avg for each value (-4, 0, 4), build the square (16, 0, 16), sum them up (32) and divide by count (3) => 10.66

Is this correct, or do I need a square root somewhere ;) ?

Note, that I had to correct the mean calculation. For 1, 5, 9, the mean is 5, not 1 - am I right? It now uses `sort -n` (numeric) and `(len+1)/2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but is there a way that I can process a whole profile? like I can use the command `./solution file.txt`

Comment: I added a function which calls the 3 calculations, and some codelines, to process a file, which is named 'data' in my example. Hope it helps.

Comment: @BrianJames: Well - if you allow to use `bc`, you gain the possibility to calculate floating point values, which might be very useful, but then you would solve the whole problem in bc - it would be a complete different thing. Give me some moments.

Comment: Thank you so much. The fomula for variance you used is correct. not need sqaure root, which would be standard deviant. yeah for 1, 5, 9, the mean is 5. Again, really appreciate your help.

Comment: @BrianJames: Well - may I mention the formal system here, build for expressing your thanks :) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the accepted answer that causes the variance to be miscalculated.  In the `print` statement:

```
", var=" ((sum*sum) - sum2)/(NF-1)
```

should be:

```
", var=" (sum2 - ((sum*sum)/NF))/(NF-1)
```

Also, it is better to use something like [Welford's algorithm](http://jonisalonen.com/2013/deriving-welfords-method-for-computing-variance/) to calculate variance; the algorithm in the accepted answer is unstable when the variance is small relative to the mean:

```
    foo="1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 2 3";
    awk '{
      M = 0;
      S = 0;
      for (k=1; k <= NF; k++) { 
        x = $k;
        oldM = M;
        M = M + ((x - M)/k);
        S = S + (x - M)*(x - oldM);
      }
      var = S/(NF - 1);
      print " var=" var;
    }' <<< $foo
```